# Akka Port Range

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

Are there specific port ranges for which Akka will work? I previously wanted to configure it on 2550-2570, but that range isn't allowed for production for me. Can any be chosen instead in it's place?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting port as zero? I guess zero would work. Have a vague memory of reading it somewhere.

Comment: 0 just tells Akka to pick a random open port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka will bind to any port so long as it isn't currently used on that machine.

Comment: Right, but how would you limit that to use a specific range?